# XPath expression to get count of the child elements

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an XML like this

```
<Root>
   <Mgr name="X">
       <Emp name = "X1"/>
       <Emp name = "X2"/>
       <Emp name = "X3"/>
   </Mgr>
   <Mgr name="Y">
       <Emp name = "Y1"/>
       <Emp name = "Y2"/>
   </Mgr>
</Root>
```

I can easily get the total employees using this `count(/Root/Mgr/Emp)`, but I was hoping to get the count for each manager.
Something like this - '3,2'.

Answer (score 3):

### XPath 1.0

This XPath 1.0 expression,

```
concat(count(/Root/Mgr[1]/Emp), ',', count(/Root/Mgr[2]/Emp))
```

will return

```
3,2
```

for your XML, as requested.

### XPath 2.0

This XPath 2.0 expression,

```
string-join(/root/Mgr/count(Emp), ',')
```

will return

```
3,2
```

for your XML, as requested (and generalizes nicely beyond two `Mgr` elements).

Comment: It surely works with your XSLT-2.0 solution, but how would an XPath-1.0 solution look like for more than two `Mgr` nodes? (I'm sure that would be appreciated)

Comment: @zx485: To get as general as the XPath 2.0 solution in XPath 1.0 would require help from the language from which the XPath library is being called.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks for your affirmation.

Comment: @kjhughes - I get Error:DOMXPath::evaluate(): Invalid expression when I try string-join(/root/Mgr/count(Emp), ',') in an online xpath evaluator.

Comment: @Fox: The error implies that XPath 2.0 is not supported by that XPath evaluator.